# New to LaTeX. Unable to print following list

Tags: math, latex, symbols, equation

I am trying to set the following list using LaTex:

```
   1. An arrival rate \lambda\\  
   2. Upper bound of the server rate \& the waiting buffer, denoted by \mu u \& Nb \\ 
   3. Cost parameters (C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6)\\  
   4. A response time guarantee x. \\ 
   5. System parameters \{\theta i, \theta d, \theta s\} used by the ISN policy \\ 
   6. System parameter \{k\} used by the SN policy \\
   7. System parameters \{\theta, N=1\} used by the SI policy\\ 
      Output: \mu*, N* and Fc (\mu*, N*) \\
```

This gives the following error message:

```
Errors: Missing $ inserted // on point 1.
Too many }'s at end of list and Missing } inserted.
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: I do not understand which part of your question is your actual question...is the numbered list intended to by LaTeX? If so, the `\lambda\ ` does not need the second backslash, and should also be in a math environment, as follows: `$\lambda$`

Comment: I had issues printing special characters. I did not know about the $\lambda$ and the math environment. Also my first time using stackoverflow. @wesanyar Your comment helped! Errors resolved Thanks!

Comment: @VarunJoshi, - you should accect wesanyers answer below. (that will also help on you so-reputation ;-) )

Comment: @MortenSickel Oh okay. Yes I accepted it. I'm also new to StackExchange! Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: Note that this question might better fit on the [tex.se] Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you use special characters in LaTeX, such as `\lambda`, you need to be sure you place it in a math environment. You can do this "in line" by wrapping it in dollar signs:

```
$\lambda$
```

Alternatively, for larger blocks of math text, you can do this:

```
\begin{math}
    \lambda = \mu * \frac{2}{3}
\end{math}
```

Also, since you are new to LaTeX, I'll point out the use of `\text`, which is handy if you need to include some non-math characters in your equation:

```
$\lambda = \text{MyVariable} * x_{\text{a_long_description}}$
```

update: as [dlfri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35096383/4608626) points out, you'll want to use the `enumerate` environment rather than manually typing your numbers:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First sub-item
        \item Second sub-item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Third Item
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather then manually entering the numbers for your enumerated list, you could preferably use the `enumerate` environment. If making use of math commands and symbol in plain text, remember to wrap them in `$...$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item An arrival rate $\lambda$ 
    \item Upper bound of the server rate \& the waiting buffer, denoted by $\mu$, $u$, \& $N_b$ 
    \item Cost parameters $(C_0, C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5, C_6)$  
    \item A response time guarantee $x$
    \item System parameters $\{\theta_i, \theta_d, \theta_s\}$ used by the ISN policy
    \item System parameter $\{k\}$ used by the SN policy
    \item System parameters $\{\theta, N=1\}$ used by the SI policy
    \item Output: $\mu^*$, $N^*$ and $F_c(\mu^*, N^*)$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Yields

[image]